# How to implement a correct filtering in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a `modelA`, `modelB`, and `modelC`. `modelA` hasMany `modelB`, `modelB` belongsTo `modelA`, `modelB` belongsTo `modelC`.

Below is my computed property on my `component.js`  and the code below is I want to get all the `modelA` where the `modelC` id is equal to the baz.id

```
foo: computed('modelA', 'baz.id', function() {
  return this.get('modelA').filter((a) => {
    return a.get('modelB').filter((b) => {
      let userId = b.get('modelC.id');
      let bazId = this.get('baz.id');

      if (userId === bazId) {
        return b;
      }
    })
  });
}),
```

Issue: I am not getting the correct response. The response is not equivalent to my expectations.
Question: Did I implement the computed property correctly based on my desired scenario which is I want to get all the `modelA` where the `modelC` id is equal to the `baz.id`

Appreciate for any response. Thank you

Comment: Hey @Mikelemuel have you had a chance to take a look at my answer? If it was helpful I would appreciate if you accept and up-vote to let me know that it worked :) if not then let me know and I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola @Mikelemuel, thanks for your question

I'm having a bit of difficulty in understanding what you're trying to ask I'm going to first lay out what I think you are asking and then proceed to answer the question as I understand it.

Firstly you say `I want to get all the modelA where the modelC id is equal to the baz.id` which is hard to understand. Firstly I would recommend that you don't call these `modelA` etc. because it's hard to figure out what you're asking and it's hard to forumulate an answer. If you can give me proper names for these models I will update them in this answer.

Based on what I understand of your relationships this is the setup that I have created:

```js
// app/models/model-a.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  children: DS.hasMany('modelB'),
})
```

```js
// app/models/model-b.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  parent: DS.belongsTo('modelA'),
  sibling: DS.belongsTo('modelC'),
})
```

```js
// app/models/model-c.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  sibling: DS.belongsTo('modelB'),
})
```

I built these models from the description of the relationships that you gave. Please let me know if they are incorrect or if you have a better name for each of the attribute names.

Now to rephrase the query that you're looking for:

> I want to filter all model-a (which is the main query) where they have
>   any children who's sibling has an ID equal to the id of this.baz

With this, I created a simple route that just creates some dummy data. This isn't important to the answer but it's useful to see what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
// app/routes/application.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    let result = this.store.createRecord('model-a');

    let children = [
      this.store.createRecord('model-b', {
        parent: result
      }),

      this.store.createRecord('model-b', {
        parent: result
      })
    ];

    this.store.createRecord('model-c', {
      id: 'five',
      sibling: children[1]
    });

    return [result];
  }
});
```

and with that we are able to create the computed property you were describing in the controller:

```js
// app/controllers/application.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  baz: computed(function() {
    return {
      id: 'five',
    }
  }),

  foo: computed('model', 'baz.id', function() {
    let result = this.model.filter((item) => {
      return item.children.find((child) => {
        return child.get('sibling.id') === this.get('baz.id');
      })
    });

    return result;
  }),
});
```

firstly you will see that I have a `baz` computed property that I'm just using to make it so that `this.get('baz.id')` returns something. I imagine in your use case you're setting `this.baz` to be something dynamically.

The next thing that you will notice is that I'm using a mixture of `filter()` and `find()` in my function. It is worth reminding yourself how `filter()` works by [checking out the JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but essentially you need to return a **truthy** value for the item in the array to be included in the result.

To provide this truthy value we are making use of [JavaScript find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which will find the first instance where the result of the provided function is truthy.

I have tested this locally and it works as expected (based on my understanding of your question).

I hope this was helpful